# Joomla - Caching causes Problems with forms

Tags: php, forms, apache, caching, joomla

Most of the times, when I want to send a form with CKForms, the plugin does not recognize it and I get a blank page. 
The HTTP Post definitely arrives at the server, I can see that in the Logfiles. When I use another Form Plugin (proforms) the same thing happens.
I'm pretty sure that the problem has something to do with caching! I disabled caching in the joomla backend (in the Server configurations menu and in the Plugin menu) and even tried deleting the cache calls in the plugin file. 
I am running Joomla 1.5 on a Apache2 Server. 
Could the solution be to disable Caching for this Plugin globally (maybe in the Apache Configuration)? And if so, how can I do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Apache has nothing to do with Joomla caching.

The plugin's output may be cached by both the page cache and the component's cache, depending on which event it runs.

CKForms has a good reputation, and having two components throw the same error brings the attention away from them.

Are you using some non-ascii characters in the form names/fields? Does the Joomla contact form work? Is your system clean (no malware etc.)?

The blank page means Joomla encountered an exception / error and didn't finish rendering the page.  The information about the error is available in the server php log (not apache `error_log`, I mean the php error log). You can find the error log location looking it up from the tools/ system information menu in the Joomla administrator or looking at your `php.ini`.  Beware, some hosts have it disabled and you need to turn it on explicitly.
This will contain the error thrown, the file that threw it and the line with the offending code.

Joomla cache has a mechanism to replace the `token` which now and then broke in older versions, make sure you're using a patched up 1.5.26 version.

Needless to say, your error would also be fixed with an update to 2.5 or 3.x and you should consider it as Joomla1.5 has been dead for a while now.